# Загрузка ХР с внешнего носителя

Tags: windows, железо

Мне нужно установить `Windows ХР` на съёмный носитель (любой) так, чтобы с ней можно было работать в обычном режиме: установка и удаление программ, обновление антивируса и т.д.. Работать предполагается на одной материнке, совместимость с другими МВ не интересует. Возможно ли это, и если "Да", то как? В интернете находил только "Live-CD" или установочные (для установки системы на HDD).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

поставить довольно не сложно
http://flashboot.ru/index.php?name=News&op=article&sid=8

сам ставил, но выдерживает около 20 загрузок из-за глючности fat32, сама флешка сдохла через год, на такую активность оно не расчитанно

Comment: Спасибо! Страничку эту видел, но не пробовал. При таком варианте установки ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО сохраняются изменения? Бог с ней, с флешкой!

Answer (score 0):

Есл мать поддерживает загрузку винды с носителя тогда есть шанс установить. Но! Есть ли смысл этого гемора если чтение данных с носителя является не опретивной!?

Comment: Извини, я не профи - что значит "опретивной" не понял... Видимо, связано со скоростью работы?
Мать внешнюю загрузку поддерживает, а смысл в том, что у меня на работе очень НЕ поощряются проги, установленные НЕ сисадмином, а выход в НЭТ - вообще криминал! Даже следы "флешек" приходится удалять, чтоб не нарваться! В таких условиях, сам понимаешь, можно пожертвовать скоростью...